# epsilon-neighborhood for polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, distance, nearest-neighbor, dbscan

I am having a density-based radar database that I try to cluster with a grid-based DBSCAN algorithm.

To safe processing time, I do not want to transform the polar coordinates to Euclidean space.

The part of the algorithm my question focuses on is "the core point condition". Which is basically the following. To determine if a point is a core point, it needs to have more than a certain number of neighbours (MinPoints) in its epsilon-neighbourhood.

The epsilon neighbourhood can be determined as follows:

1. Calculate the distance from a point *P* to all the other points in the database.
2. Determine the epsilon-neighbourhood: All the points that are within a max. distance of *eps* are part of the neighbourhood. Meaning epsilon is the search radius.
3. The core point condition: A point is a core point if in its epsilon-neighbourhood at least MinPoints are.

My question is now, how to determine the epsilon-neighbourhood for polar points with azimuth (azi) and range (r). I do not completely know how to calculate the distance and then from there how to determine the epsilon neighbourhood.

***My final goal:***
A radar is having a non-equidistant distant sampling density which means that point close to the radar are closer spaced in azimuth direction than points in a large range. Therefore, I want implement a range dependent epsilon vector, eps(r) that defines the search radius in epsilon direction.

---

A simple method:

---

A simple method is to calculate the distance of p and q for each dimension.

Then I can determine the epsilon neighbourhood in each dimension. You can imagine it as a cross +. Checking for eps_azi and eps_r linearly.

Question: How can I find the neighbours in a circle or ellipse. So all the points that are not on the cross but still in the neighbourhood.

I tried to illustrate my problem:
[Sketch problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZshLS.png)

In red is the simple solution and in blue the more advanced circle/ellipse solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should google how to measure distances between polar points. A simple way would be to transform the polar coordinates to Euclidean space and then use Euclidean distance.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.
I know how to measure the distance in polar points ( sqrt{(r_1)^2+(r_2)^2−2*r_1r_2cos(θ_1−θ_2)}. I do not know how to apply that distance when I want to, e.g., include 3 elements in azimuth angle and 5 in range.
Secondly, I want to save processing time and therefore not transform it to Euclidean space. 
I will edit my question so you know what my final goal is.

Comment: If you can calculate the distance between two points, then you can easily find the neighborhood using epsilon as the threshold (DBSCAN does that for you). I am assuming that you are implementing your own DBSCAN so you can directly work with polar coordinates. Many existing implementations of DBSCAN also accept a distance matrix. So you could pre-calculate the distance matrix for your coordinates and use that. However, this improbably more expensive than converting the coordinates to Euclidean space.

Comment: I think, that I formulated my question maybe a bit misleading. The problem with the radar data is, because it has an azimuth sampling resolution, the conversion in Euclidean space results in a non-equidistant density which has an influence on the performance of DBSCAN. I found a method online that suggests using a range-dependant eps. That means I have two search radii (in range and in azimuth). I want to know how to apply the above-explained core point condition on these.